# Once added, remove a value from dropdown menu and show the next value, also once deleted, add the deleted value once again to the dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I am using below procedure to add Month and value to a table using the dropdown menu and text box. My requirement is that once the data is added , remove that Month from the dropdown menu and show the next corresponding Month in the list to the user. Also if the record(s) is/were removed, re-add that removed value(s) to the dropdown menu as well. User need to tick the records from the table that needs to be deleted.

Data insertion method

```js
function ftm2add5() {
  var cat = $("#month").val();
  var amt = $("#amt5").val();

  var cate = $("#month option:selected").html();

  if (amt == "") {
    $("#amt5").addClass("red-border");
  } else {

    if ($('#table5 tr:contains("' + cate + '")').length > 0) {
      alert("found duplicate values");
    } else {
      var markup =
        "<tr><td><input type='checkbox'  name='record'></td><td>" +
        cat +
        "</td><td>" +
        amt +
        "</td></tr>";
      $("#table5 tbody").append(markup);

      $("#amt5").val(null);
    }
  }
}


function deleteval(z, a) {

  // Find and remove selected table rows

  $("#" + z + "" + " tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).parents("tr").remove();
    }
  });


  $("#" + a + "" + " tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).parents("tr").remove();
    }
  });


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3> Montly Sales </h3>
<select id="month">
  <option value="JAN">JAN</option>
  <option value="FEB">FEB</option>
  <option value="MARCH">MARCH</option>
  <option value="APRIL">APRIL</option>
  <option value="MAY">MAY</option>
  <option value="JUNE">JUNE</option>
  <option value="JULY">JULY</option>
  <option value="AUGUST">AUGUST</option>
</select>
<input type="number" id="amt5" placeholder="Enter amount" />
<input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="ftm2add5()">
<button type="button" class="btn-danger" id="delete" onclick="deleteval('table5')">Delete Rows</button>
<table id="table5" class="table table-dark" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>T/O Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer both removes ***and re-adds*** the clicked items *(make sure all answers do both)*.

It does so by adding a `hidden` class - not by removing the SELECT option - making it easy to simply un-hide the option if the row is deleted.

```js
function ftm2add5() {
 var cat = $("#month").val();
 var amt = $("#amt5").val();

 var cate = $("#month option:selected").html();

 if (amt == "") {
  $("#amt5").addClass("red-border");
 } else {

  if ($('#table5 tr:contains("' + cate + '")').length > 0) {
   alert("found duplicate values");
  } else {
   var markup =
    "<tr><td><input type='checkbox'  name='record'></td><td>" +
    cat +
    "</td><td>" +
    amt +
    "</td></tr>";
   $("#table5 tbody").append(markup);

   $("#amt5").val(null);
  }
 }
  $("#month option:selected").addClass('hidden'); //<===== Added
  let nextMonth = $("#month option:selected").next('option').text(); //<===== Added
    $('#month').val(nextMonth);
}


function deleteval(z, a) {

 // Find and remove selected table rows

 $("#" + z + "" + " tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function () {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    let mnth = $(this).parents("tr").find('td:nth-child(2)').text(); // HERE
   $(this).parents("tr").remove();
    $('select option').each(function(){ //<================ HERE
     if ( $(this).val() === mnth ){
      $(this).removeClass('hidden');
     }
    });
  }
 });


 $("#" + a + "" + " tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function () {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
   $(this).parents("tr").remove();
  }
 });


}
```

```css
.hidden{display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3> Montly Sales  </h3>
<select  id="month">
   <option value="JAN">JAN</option>
   <option value="FEB">FEB</option>
   <option value="MARCH">MARCH</option>
   <option value="APRIL">APRIL</option>
   <option value="MAY">MAY</option>
   <option value="JUNE">JUNE</option>
   <option value="JULY">JULY</option>
   <option value="AUGUST">AUGUST</option>
</select>
<input type="number" id="amt5" placeholder ="Enter amount"/>
<input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="ftm2add5()">
<button type="button" class="btn-danger" id = "delete" onclick="deleteval('table5')" >Delete Rows</button>
<table id="table5" class="table table-dark" border="1">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Select</th>
         <th>Month</th>
         <th>T/O Value</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

---

#### UPDATE:

Per comment request, updated to also display the "next" month in the drop-down when a row is added.  There is one more thing to do, which I leave as an exercise for the OP. What happens if the user selects the final month? The code can't handle it. Here's how to solve that:

1. Before you get the "next" month, first get the selected month name (almost same code, just easier).
2. Then compare that to the text of the last item in the drop-down (start with hard-coding it to "AUGUST", then when you've got that working, figure that out programmatically)
3. IF the selected month is equal to the last name in the drop-down, set the drop-down to the first option (exact same method as in my code).

*Bonne chance!*

Comment: Thank you for your answer Friend, in here once the record is added, is there a possibility to change to the dropdown menu automatically before clicking ??

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand your question. Please clarify how you want the drop-down menu to change, and when? (Before clicking... what?  What does this have to do with the record being added?)  *Happy to help - just cannot see in my mind what you want to happen*

Comment: Actually I need to add the value first to the table , then in the same time show the next value in the drop down .. Eg When add Jan show Feb to the end user in the drop down menu ..

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind support.. Again thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var selectbox = $("#month").val();

function ftm2add5() {
 var cat = $("#month").val();
 var amt = $("#amt5").val();

 var cate = $("#month option:selected").html();

 if (amt == "") {
  $("#amt5").addClass("red-border");
 } else {

  if ($('#table5 tr:contains("' + cate + '")').length > 0) {
   alert("found duplicate values");
  } else {
   var markup =
    "<tr><td><input type='checkbox'  name='record'></td><td>" +
    cat +
    "</td><td>" +
    amt +
    "</td></tr>";
   $("#table5 tbody").append(markup);

   $("#amt5").val(null);
  }
 }
  $("#month option:selected").remove();
}


function deleteval(z, a) {

 // Find and remove selected table rows

 $("#" + z + "" + " tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function () {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#month").append('<option value="'+selectbox+'">'+selectbox+'</option>');
   $(this).parents("tr").remove();
  }
 });

 $("#" + a + "" + " tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function () {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
   $(this).parents("tr").remove();
  }
 });


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3> Montly Sales  </h3>
<select  id="month">
   <option value="JAN">JAN</option>
   <option value="FEB">FEB</option>
   <option value="MARCH">MARCH</option>
   <option value="APRIL">APRIL</option>
   <option value="MAY">MAY</option>
   <option value="JUNE">JUNE</option>
   <option value="JULY">JULY</option>
   <option value="AUGUST">AUGUST</option>
</select>
<input type="number" id="amt5" placeholder ="Enter amount"/>
<input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="ftm2add5()">
<button type="button" class="btn-danger" id = "delete" onclick="deleteval('table5')" >Delete Rows</button>
<table id="table5" class="table table-dark" border="1">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Select</th>
         <th>Month</th>
         <th>T/O Value</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment friend, in here upon delete, same value is adding ,, Eg JAN is continuously adding..